# mysql calculation

Tags: mysql

This is my initial question....well I got a response but I'm still stuck.
Can anyone please explain how can I achieve this in mysql:

I have two fields in mysql, '`cap_commdate`' with DATE TYPE and '`cap_policyterm`' with INT TYPE. I want to have another field called '`cap_maturityDate`' which will automatically compute the policy term pereod in years (in layman's term ie: `cap_commdate*cap_policyterm`). What is the right SQL query to use; or what is the best approach; and I want to use it in my recordset to prepare a confirmation page... please a simple explanation...

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(cap_commdate, INTERVAL cap_policyterm YEAR) ...
```

I ran the query and got errors; so i edited it and used:

```
SELECT
DATE_ADD("cap_commdate", INTERVAL "cap_policyterm" YEAR) AS cap_maturity FROM capital
```

All I got was empty fields. Please help out.

Comment: cap_commdate*cap_policyterm: shouldn't this be cap_commdate+cap_policyterm (seems odd to multiply those terms)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(cap_commdate, INTERVAL cap_policyterm YEAR)
...
```

This `DATE_ADD` function adds the given number of years to the starting date, thus producing the maturity date — just as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the errors you get. The query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(cap_commdate, INTERVAL cap_policyterm YEAR) FROM capital
```

should work.