# How can I resolve this issue using an sql query

Tags: mysql

This is my initial question....well I got a response but I'm still stuck.
Can anyone please explain how can I achieve this in mysql:

I have two fields in mysql, '`cap_commdate`' with DATE TYPE and '`cap_policyterm`' with INT TYPE. I want to have another field called '`cap_maturityDate`' which will automatically compute the policy term pereod in years (in Layman's expression ie: `cap_commdate*cap_policyterm`). What is the right SQL query to use; or what is the best approach; and I want to use it in my recordset to prepare a confirmation page... please a simple explanation...

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(cap_commdate, INTERVAL cap_policyterm YEAR) ...
```

I ran the query and got errors; so i edited it and used:

```
SELECT
DATE_ADD("cap_commdate", INTERVAL "cap_policyterm" YEAR) AS cap_maturity FROM capital
```

All I got was empty fields. Please help out.

Comment: Please edit your original question (and/or add a comment on answers given for it) instead of creating a second question with the same topic. Thanks!

Comment: unrelated: you probably meant "layman's terms" instead of "lame man's expression". It's a small but significant difference which could end up being very embarrassing when sent to the wrong person ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318398/mysql-calculation is what Dav is referring to, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the field names

```
SELECT
DATE_ADD(cap_commdate, INTERVAL cap_policyterm YEAR) AS cap_maturity FROM capital
```

I think this should work.

I know its is an old question, but just trying to help others